# WPF making ServiceController[] Observable

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, observablecollection, servicecontroller

So im trying to make a data-grid that displays some information about local window services, mine in particular, I would like to have the display name and status of the service, and then have a button to click to start or stop. I can link the button method up fine, but the service status does not change, any suggestions an how to make this property observable to the datagrid, and also possible change the button on the fly from start to stop based on the status, secondly I would like to make the stop command be be a button command if possibe.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up implamenting. It works pretty well for the most part, however I up for any code suggestions anyone might.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace v7quickbar
{
    class NotifiableServiceController : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private ServiceController m_oServiceController = null;
        private System.Timers.Timer m_oServiceCheckTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public ServiceControllerStatus Status { get { return this.m_oServiceController.Status; } }

        public string DisplayName { get { return this.m_oServiceController.DisplayName; } }

        public string ServiceName { get { return this.m_oServiceController.ServiceName; } }

        public bool CanStop { get { return this.m_oServiceController.CanStop; } }

        public NotifiableServiceController(ServiceController oService)
        {
            CreateObject(oService, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5));
        }

        public NotifiableServiceController(ServiceController oService, TimeSpan oInterval)
        {
            CreateObject(oService, oInterval);
        }

        private void CreateObject(ServiceController oService, TimeSpan oInterval)
        {
            m_oServiceController = oService;
            m_oServiceCheckTimer.Interval = oInterval.TotalMilliseconds;

            m_oServiceCheckTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(m_oServiceCheckTimer_Elapsed);
            m_oServiceCheckTimer.Start();
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            try
            {
                this.m_oServiceController.Start();
                this.m_oServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            try
            {
                this.m_oServiceController.Stop();
                this.m_oServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        public void Restart()
        {
            try
            {
                if (m_oServiceController.CanStop && (m_oServiceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running || m_oServiceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Paused))
                {
                    this.Stop();
                    this.m_oServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                }

                if (m_oServiceController.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    this.Start();
                    this.m_oServiceController.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
            }
        }

        void m_oServiceCheckTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceControllerStatus oCurrentStatus = m_oServiceController.Status;
            m_oServiceController.Refresh();

            if (oCurrentStatus != m_oServiceController.Status)
            {
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Status"));
            }

        }

        public static IEnumerable<NotifiableServiceController> GetServices()
        {
            List<NotifiableServiceController> oaServices = new List<NotifiableServiceController>();
            foreach (ServiceController sc in ServiceController.GetServices())
            {
                oaServices.Add(new NotifiableServiceController(sc));
            }

            return oaServices;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your the service into your own class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged. As you start/stop the service, raise property change event on that instance.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly because `ServiceController.GetServices()` call would always return an array, we have to have `DispatcherTimer` and in its tick, make call to `ServiceController.GetServices()` and raise notify property changed for that property that holds the array of services.

Making it observable for the sake of observability isnt practical right? We wont gain any advantage out of it anyways.

Comment: I ended up doing something like this  ServiceController sc = ((ServiceController)elem.DataContext);
   if (sc.CanStop && sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
   {
    sc.Stop();
    sc.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    sc.Refresh();
    V7ServicesGrid.Items.Refresh(); 
   }